# ZF2 phpunit URL-ViewHelper

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, zend-framework2

I want to test my application. Everything works fine to the point where i want to test my own viewHelpers (actionHelpers).
The problem is, i want to use the url-ViewHelper in my own viewHelper to generate links.

Therefore i use this statements.

```
$urlHelper = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('url');
$urlHelper->__invoke('test',array(),array(),true);
```

This works great.

But now i want to test parts of my application where my view helper is used. Everything works fine to the point where i use the url_ViewHelper.

I get following exception:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getRouteMatch() on a non-object in ****\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewHelperManagerFactory.php on line 70
```

Is there something wrong in the way i setUp my test?

```
$serviceManager = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();
$this->controller = new IndexController();
$this->request = new Request();
$this->routeMatch = new RouteMatch(array('controller' => 'index'));
$this->event = new MvcEvent();
$config = $serviceManager->get('Config');
$routerConfig = isset($config['router']) ? $config['router'] : array();
$router = HttpRouter::factory($routerConfig);
$this->event->setRouter($router);
$this->event->setRouteMatch($this->routeMatch);
$this->controller->setEvent($this->event);
$this->controller->setServiceLocator($serviceManager);
```

Thank you very much for help!